# How can i import a iwindowssession obejct?

Tags: java, android

I need to use an instance of `android.view.iwindowssession` but I can´t import the package of the class. Can you help me? I only have the aidl file of this class.

I want to send a parcel to an `iwindowssession` and I am using this to get the `windowsession`:

```
    WindowManager window = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    IBinder windowsession = IWindowSession.Stub.asInterface(window);
```

But I can't import the class of `IWindowSession`.

Comment: Please provide code showing what you have tried, error(s) received, etc.  Your question is not clear enough for the community to provide you with assistance.

Comment: sorry. i edit the question.